# C# - How can i get value for each column in a row on combobox value change events?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

[image]

Hai everyone. For each column in a row, how can i get all the value in that columns on combobox values change events. It can be either on combobox in "Destination" or "Data_type" column. I'm think something like this example on text column:

```
            string Source = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string Destination = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string Similarity = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string Datatype = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

Example code or suggestion on the best way possible to this are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx) 
and
[`DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.110).aspx) 
will give you current row index irrespective of whether current control is combobox, textbox or readonly cell. use it in your logic. From name of property its obvious that it will give you current cell or row object. use it as per your need.

I prefer to use `CurrentRow` property because it directly gives current row object. and instead of hard coded column index in `Cell` property, I will prefer to use ColumnObject.Index property. so in case if we change column order, no need to change code.
For example:

> string Source =
>   dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[colSourceName.Index].Value.ToString();

*(here i guess Source_Name column Name is colSourceName)*

**Edit:**
I use it in [`EditingControlShowing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing(v=vs.110).aspx) event of DataGridView.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colSourceName.Index)
    {
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectedIndexChanged -= cmb_SelectedIndexChanged;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectedIndexChanged += cmb_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}
```

First it tries to detach event so if user comes 2nd time on same combobox, it do not fire it 2 time. and then re-attaching event.
You have two combobox, so you need to add condition accordingly.

Comment: i'm sorry. Maybe my question is a lil bit vague. Although your suggestion did help but i am interested to know which events that i can use to get all value from each column in a row when the combobox changes value. I hope you can give me your input on this

Comment: I use "EditingControlShowing" event. Please check edited reply.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps me a lot